# (Phonegap) How to clear local notifications on app close / killed instead of app pause

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap, localnotification

I'm using both cordova-plugin-local-notifications and phonegap-plugin-push. I understand that by default phonegap-plugin-push will clear all notifications when the app goes to pause state.

My local notification is a running clock notification (like a stopwatch), so I don't want this notification to be cleared when the app is in pause state, because the clock in notification is still running, so I added clearNotifications:"false" to the init.

```
const push = PushNotification.init({
    android: { clearNotifications:"false" }
});
```

However, I realized that I can only clear the notifications during pause state. I'm not able to clear notifications when the app get closed / killed by user (e.g. swiping in background). Meaning that any ongoing clock local notification will still appear and running on the notification tray even after the app closed.

I've googled all around and still can't find any solution on this.

May I know is there any way to clear the notifications when the app get closed / killed? It would be great if you could guide me, thank you.

Comment: Cannot test right now, but try using `window.onbeforeunload` or `window.onunload`?

Comment: Hi @D_N , I've tried with $(window).bind("beforeunload",function(event) { }); & $(window).bind("unload",function(event) { }); but none of them working. Thanks.

Comment: I'm also trying to clone both repositories and make some changes, for **phonegap-plugin-push** I try to clear notifications `onDestroy()`, however, it seems like it's not firing, after googling, I found that this approach is not guaranteed. So I tried another way which is for **cordova-plugin-local-notifications**, I added `startForeground();` for `public Notification build()` . As I'm not familiar with Android, this turned out to be `error: cannot find symbol` in **PhonegapBuild**. I'm a newbie in Android/Ios, so I'm not sure that I'm doing the correct way, thank you.